# Cleaner way to detect if a particular package was installed in apt-get hook?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have a simple script that applies a patch to a given package, and, since each time said package is upgraded the patch gets overridden, I would really like to automatically apply the patch after every upgrade.

To accomplish this, I created a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` and added a hook for `DPkg::Post-Invoke`. As documented by `man apt-get`, this hook is run by `apt-get` after installing a package with `dpkg`. However this hook does not seem to have any information whatsoever about *which particular package* has been installed, so I cannot know if I have to apply the patch or not. Nothing gets passed to its stdin, nothing gets passed as argument, and the man page says nothing about it.

So to solve this I did the only thing that I could think of: I added another hook for `DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs`, which gets run by `apt-get` *before* packages are installed. This hook gets (through stdin) the list of `.deb` files which are going to be installd by `dpkg`, so I just check whether any file name matches the name of the package I want to patch, and if so I create a file in `/tmp`. When my other hook is executed, it first checks for the existence of said file and, if present, applies the patch to the package that has just been installed.

Here's the file I've created in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`:

```
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {
    "while read -r pkg; do case $pkg in *somepkg*) touch /tmp/.patch && exit 0; esac done < /dev/stdin";
};

DPkg::Post-Invoke {
    "[ -f /tmp/.patch ] && /home/marco/scripts/apply_somepkg_patch.sh && rm -f /tmp/.patch; exit 0";
};
```

**To be clear**: the `apply_somepkg_patch.sh` simply edits the contents of a file provided by the package. I want said file to be *upgraded and patched* each time, I don't want to "lock" it so it doesn't get upgraded.

Now, while this all works just fine, it looks really dirty and somehow wrong to me. **Is there any cleaner way to accomplish this?** Perhaps only using the `DPkg::Post-Invoke` hook? Or, in other words, is there a way to know which package got installed in the `DPkg::Post-Invoke` hook?

---

**EDIT**: adding a detailed example of what I'm doing just to be 101% clear, even though I don't think it adds any more information to what I said above.

Suppose `somepkg` is the package I'm talking about, and `somefile` is the file installed by such package which I want to patch.

1. First installation of `somepkg`, content of `somefile`:

   ```
   some_opt1 = some_value
   some_opt2 = some_value
   some_opt3 = a, b, c, d
   some_opt4 = some_value
   ```
2. Apply patch, changing it to:

   ```
   some_opt1 = some_value
   some_opt2 = some_value
   some_opt3 = X, Y, Z, d
   some_opt4 = some_value
   ```
3. Upgrade of `somepkg`, contents `somefile` after upgrade:

   ```
   some_opt1 = some_value
   some_opt2 = some_value
   some_opt5 = some_value
   some_opt3 = a, b, c, d
   some_opt6 = some_value
   some_opt4 = some_value
   ```
4. Apply patch, changing it to:

   ```
   some_opt1 = some_value
   some_opt2 = some_value
   some_opt5 = some_value
   some_opt3 = X, Y, Z, d
   some_opt6 = some_value
   some_opt4 = some_value
   ```

Now, what's the `somepackage`, where `somefile` is, what's inside `somefile`: this is all *completely irrelevant* for my question. All you need to know is that **I want to dynamically modify the contents of `somefile`, which is part of `somepkg`, after getting the upgraded version of the file**.

This obviously cannot be done statically: I need a script to read `somefile`, parse its content and patch it accordingly. Therefore, if I want my script to be automatically ran each time `somepkg` gets updated, I need to make `apt-get` run it automatically for me.

Comment: “each time said package is upgraded the patch gets overridden” Have you tried `dpkg-divert`? Most patches can be made persistent with a local diversion (but not all, e.g. if you need to patch only part of a file).

Comment: @Gilles I don't think I get what you're saying: if you're suggesting to use `dpkg-divert` to "lock" a file and prevent it from being modified, I don't want this. I want the file to be updated and, only then, patched.

Comment: Do the package have a .d directory?

Comment: @Braiam No, it does not. It is a simple package which only consists of a binary program and some configuration files. I just want to keep patching one of those programmatically after each upgrade.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the specifics of your patch? There are a number of possible approaches, but which one is best depends on the precise scenario.

Comment: @StephenKitt I added a more detailed and thorough explanation of what I'm exactly doing.

Comment: I agree your edit doesn’t add anything substantive ;-). I still think it would be useful to know exactly which package and which file you’re patching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no nice way to do this with `apt` or `dpkg` hooks of the style you’re currently using. There might be a simple way of handling such patches on upgrades for the specific package and file you’re modifying, but if you want a generic solution, I think the best approach in Debian currently is to use [file triggers](http://eric.van-der-vlist.com/blog/owark/473/).

This involves creating a (simple) package which will take care of patching the file on upgrades of the other package (the one containing the file you wish to patch). Your patching package needs to declare its interest in a file trigger; to do so, add a file named `debian/triggers`) containing the single line

```
interest /path/to/the/file/to/patch
```

Then in the package’s `postinst` (`debian/postinst`), check if the first argument is `triggered`, and if it is, run your patching script (or merge that in your `postinst`). If you want to keep your patching script separate, you could ship it in your patching package to keep things contained.

Once all that’s done, build and install your patching package, and then whenever you upgrade the package you’re modifying, your patching package’s `postinst` will be called.

Comment: Wow that's really neat. I spent some time looking around and came across triggers too, but I never thought about creating my own package just to use a trigger. Thanks for your answer, will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: I successfully created a custom package like you sugested and it seems to work like a charm! One thing that should be noted though is that `lintian` emits a warning `uses-implicit-await-trigger` for the `interest` trigger, so I replaced the trigger name with `interests-await` to be explicit. Thanks again for the answer.